# Educational - Combine SQL queries (UNION ALL Example)

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get better at SQL as I program and would like to combine the following 3 SQL queries/code into one SQL call - is it possible? (I realize it won't come out formatted 100% as I have it specifically the `monthly_totals` but if that's possible too...?)

*Note: The code provided below should give you an idea of the structure of my databases as well as what I'm trying to accomplish.*

```
$ret = array(
    'raw' => array(),
    'total' => '0.00',
    'monthly_totals' => array()
);
if (!empty($sales_rep_id)) {
    $orders = $this->query("
            SELECT
                id,
                invoice_no,
                CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name,
                affiliate_id,
                commission,
                YEAR(created) as created_year,
                MONTH(created) as created_month,
                created
            FROM orders
            WHERE 
                active = 1 AND
                affiliate_id = {$sales_rep_id}
            ORDER BY MONTH(created) DESC
                    ");

    if (!empty($orders)) {
        $total = $this->query("
                SELECT SUM(commission) as commission_total
                FROM orders
                WHERE
                    active = 1 AND
                    affiliate_id = {$sales_rep_id} 
               ");
        $raw_monthly_totals = $this->query("
            SELECT
                MONTH(created) as month_no,
                SUM(commission) as monthly_commission
            FROM orders
            WHERE 
                active = 1 AND
                affiliate_id = {$sales_rep_id}
            GROUP BY MONTH(created)
                ");

        $monthly_totals = array();
        foreach ($raw_monthly_totals as $tot) {
            $monthly_totals[$tot['month_no']] = $tot['monthly_commission'];
        }

        $ret['raw'] = $orders;
        $ret['total'] = $total[0]['commission_total'];
        $ret['monthly_totals'] = $monthly_totals;
    }
}
return $ret;
```

### Current output

```
array(4) {
  ["raw"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "5335"
      ["invoice_no"]=>
      string(15) "5335-1395260183"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "First Last"
      ["affiliate_id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["commission"]=>
      string(6) "100.88"
      ["created_year"]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      ["created_month"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["created"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-19 14:16:23"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "5373"
      ["invoice_no"]=>
      string(15) "5373-1396031594"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "First Last"
      ["affiliate_id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["commission"]=>
      string(6) "294.27"
      ["created_year"]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      ["created_month"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["created"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-28 12:33:14"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "5374"
      ["invoice_no"]=>
      string(15) "5374-1396043777"
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "First M. Last"
      ["affiliate_id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["commission"]=>
      string(6) "122.16"
      ["created_year"]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      ["created_month"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["created"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-28 15:56:17"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "5378"
      ["invoice_no"]=>
      string(15) "5378-1396044619"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "First Last"
      ["affiliate_id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["commission"]=>
      string(6) "100.88"
      ["created_year"]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      ["created_month"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["created"]=>
      string(19) "2014-03-28 16:10:19"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "5372"
      ["invoice_no"]=>
      string(15) "5372-1396031586"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "First Last"
      ["affiliate_id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["commission"]=>
      string(6) "294.27"
      ["created_year"]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      ["created_month"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["created"]=>
      string(19) "2014-02-28 12:33:06"
    }
  }
  ["total"]=>
  string(6) "912.46"
  ["pending"]=>
  string(4) "0.00"
  ["monthly_totals"]=>
  array(2) {
    [2]=>
    string(6) "294.27"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "618.19"
  }
}
```

Comment: generally speaking: if you're running nested queries and the inner queries depend on/use data from the outer queries, then USUALLY you can combine them into a single `JOIN`ed query.

Comment: Right, but I don't know how to: (1) `GROUP BY` and get the individual "raw" order data with the `monthly_totals` as well as (2) the `total`(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure can. I added a QueryDesc column to distinguish between queries.

```
$ret = array(
    'raw' => array(),
    'total' => '0.00',
    'pending' => '0.00',
    'monthly_totals' => array()
);
if (!empty($sales_rep_id)) {
    $raw_query_data = $this->query("
        SELECT
            'detail' query_desc,
            id,
            invoice_no,
            CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name,
            affiliate_id,
            commission,
            YEAR(created) as created_year,
            MONTH(created) as created_month,
            created
        FROM orders
        WHERE 
            active = 1 AND
            affiliate_id = {$sales_rep_id}
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'total' query_desc,
            NULL id,
            NULL invoice_no,
            NULL name,
            NULL affiliate_id,
            SUM(commission) as commission_total,
            NULL created_year,
            NULL created_month,
            NULL created                    
        FROM orders
        WHERE
            active = 1 AND
            affiliate_id = {$sales_rep_id} 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'monthly_total' query_desc,
            NULL id,
            NULL invoice_no,
            NULL name,
            NULL affiliate_id,
            SUM(commission) as commission_total,
            NULL created_year,
            MONTH(created) as created_month,
            NULL created
        FROM orders
        WHERE 
            active = 1 AND
            affiliate_id = {$sales_rep_id}
        GROUP BY MONTH(created)
        ORDER BY created_month DESC
        ");


    foreach ($raw_query_data as $data) {
        switch ($data['query_desc']) {
            case 'detail':
                unset($data['query_desc']);
                $ret['raw'][] = $data;
                break;
            case 'monthly_total':
                $ret['monthly_totals'][$data['created_month']] = $data['commission'];
                break;
            case 'total':
                $ret['total'] = $data['commission'];
                break;
        }
    }
}

return $ret;
```

### Output [refrence]

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(6) "detail"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5335"
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    string(15) "5335-1395260183"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "First Last"
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "100.88"
    ["created_year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["created_month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-19 14:16:23"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(13) "monthly_total"
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "618.19"
    ["created_year"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["created"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(6) "detail"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5378"
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    string(15) "5378-1396044619"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "First Last"
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "100.88"
    ["created_year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["created_month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-28 16:10:19"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(6) "detail"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5374"
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    string(15) "5374-1396043777"
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "First M. Last"
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "122.16"
    ["created_year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["created_month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-28 15:56:17"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(6) "detail"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5373"
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    string(15) "5373-1396031594"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "First Last"
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "294.27"
    ["created_year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["created_month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-28 12:33:14"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(13) "monthly_total"
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "294.27"
    ["created_year"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_month"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["created"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [6]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(6) "detail"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5372"
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    string(15) "5372-1396031586"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "First Last"
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "294.27"
    ["created_year"]=>
    string(4) "2014"
    ["created_month"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-28 12:33:06"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(9) {
    ["query_desc"]=>
    string(5) "total"
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
    ["invoice_no"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["affiliate_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["commission"]=>
    string(6) "912.46"
    ["created_year"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_month"]=>
    NULL
    ["created"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never seen that syntax `'Total' QueryDesc` or the **NULL** part of `NULL id` - I am self taught though. Is there a resource you could point me to explaining what it does? I mean: I see what it does - setting a default - but I'd like to learn more :D

Comment: I can explain what it does :) `'Total' QueryDesc` adds a column to the select statement with the string value `'Total'`. `NULL id` passes a `NULL` for the `id` column since the second two queries are aggregates and don't require that column.

Comment: @Wallter You've probably seen code like this: `SELECT someColumn AS someAlias FROM someTable`. The `AS` is optional (but not a bad idea to include). In this case, instead of a column name, strings and NULL values are used. The posted example would be equivalent to `SELECT 'total' AS query_desc, NULL as id, ...`.